# Transfer entire directory using ssh2 in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sftp, scp

I'm just wondering whether it is at all possible to transfer a directory from a unix server to my local machine using the ssh2 module in node.js. I have connected to the remote host and can read the directory as well as transfer single files, but there are 28 folders in the directory which each contain files and sub directories. What I'd like to do is take an exact copy of the main directory from the server to my local machine.

I was using fastGet with single files, but transferring a directory gives: `Error: EISDIR, open __dirname/../localdirectory/` which I think implies I can't use fastGet to get an entire directory. I also tried using the exec command to try and scp it over, but I couldn't work out the syntax for the local directory:

```
// c is an active connection
c.exec('scp filethatexists.extension /../filepath/newname.extension', function(err, stream) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error: " + err);
        stream.end;
    };
    stream.on('data', function(data, extended) {
        console.log((extended === 'stderr' ? 'STDERR: ' : 'STDOUT: ') + data);
    });
    stream.on('end', function() {
        console.log('Stream :: EOF');
    });
    stream.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Stream :: close');
    });
    stream.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
        console.log('Stream :: exit :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
        c.end();
    });
});
```

This  just results in the EOF calling. This code was just me testing If I could get a single file transferring.

Can anyone provide me with any assistance? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of solutions:

1. You could recursively traverse the directory (making directories and transferring files as needed) using the `sftp` methods
2. Tar the directory (compress it too if you want) to stdout (e.g. `tar cf - mydir`) and then process that incoming stdout `data` with the [tar](https://github.com/isaacs/node-tar) module (and the built-in [zlib](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/zlib.html) module first if you end up compressing the directory).

   ```
   // Requires:
   //   * `npm install tar-fs`
   //   * `ssh2` v0.5.x or newer
   var tar = require('tar-fs');
   var zlib = require('zlib');

   function transferDir(conn, remotePath, localPath, compression, cb) {
     var cmd = 'tar cf - "' + remotePath + '" 2>/dev/null';

     if (typeof compression === 'function')
       cb = compression;
     else if (compression === true)
       compression = 6;

     if (typeof compression === 'number'
         && compression >= 1
         && compression <= 9)
       cmd += ' | gzip -' + compression + 'c 2>/dev/null';
     else
       compression = undefined;

     conn.exec(cmd, function(err, stream) {
       if (err)
         return cb(err);

       var exitErr;

       var tarStream = tar.extract(localPath);
       tarStream.on('finish', function() {
         cb(exitErr);
       });

       stream.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
         if (typeof code === 'number' && code !== 0) {
           exitErr = new Error('Remote process exited with code '
                               + code);
         } else if (signal) {
           exitErr = new Error('Remote process killed with signal '
                               + signal);
         }
       }).stderr.resume();

       if (compression)
         stream = stream.pipe(zlib.createGunzip());

       stream.pipe(tarStream);
     });
   }

   // USAGE ===============================================================
   var ssh = require('ssh2');

   var conn = new ssh();
   conn.on('ready', function() {
     transferDir(conn,
                 '/home/foo',
                 __dirname + '/download',
                 true, // uses compression with default level of 6
                 function(err) {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log('Done transferring');
       conn.end();
     });
   }).connect({
     host: '192.168.100.10',
     port: 22,
     username: 'foo',
     password: 'bar'
   });
   ```

Comment: How do I go about processing `data` with the tar module? There is a considerable lack of documentation for it.

Comment: After some changes to `ssh2`, I've updated my answer to provide a solution for tarring/gzipping.

Comment: @mscdex I was wondering how is the remotepath set. I have a folder on my server named dev I want to transfer over to my other server running node. I think the remotePath variable is the variable I would set to dev but not totally sure how this was set

Comment: @JoshuaDeshazer `remotePath` is the directory on the ssh server you wish to download.

Comment: @mscdex so in your case is remotePath set to /dev/null?

Comment: @mscdex nm I figured it out. its on the usage where you are calling the function transferdir conn, remotepath is the next string you are passing then where you want it on local path. Thanks I just needed some sleep yesterday because when I woke up today it came right to me

Answer (score -1):

i m also trying to downlaod folders using ssh. It took me more than 10 days and i'm still trying to do that. But in the mean time i found some other code which will do the same thing for me.This code below will download every folder and file inside a directory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llkln.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32635370)